# Show missing I18n translations in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview, actionviewhelper

As stated [in ActionView's documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper/translate), the `t` view helper in Rails automatically mangles missing translations. Eg:

```
irb> helper.t('words.foo_bar')
=> "<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.words.foo_bar">Foo Bar</span>"
```

Is there any way to disable this globally? I'd much rather see "*translation missing: en.words.asdf*" .

The only workaround that I've found is to use `I18n.t "..."` instead of `t "..."` in views.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this code in your `development.rb`

```
# Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
# the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
config.i18n.fallbacks = false
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @thesis. Unfortunately, that results in the same output from ActionView's `#t`.

Comment: @Ashitaka Yeah, I restarted the server after making that change. Also, the "fallbacks" option controls whether or not a failed translation tries to use the corresponding translation in the default locale. So it won't prevent the mangling that I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I have this file in my `config/initializers` directory, which shows me all translation lookups that failed and where they originated from in the log output: https://gist.github.com/1594660

Maybe this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the gist, Christoph. I guess you'd have to grep through the log every so often to look for failed translations.

Comment: Instead of grepping one should rather write the output to a database plus count the occurrence. I use my gist to discover failed translations while developing (or finding the correct key when building the locale file).

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to show the **"translation missing"** instead of the span tag is to put this in my initializer:

```
config.action_view.debug_missing_translation = false
```

This is explained in the Rails guides here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/configuring.html#configuring-action-view